# Bootstrap - change @media or CSS?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I currently have a row with 2 . Each div has a button and is fine when in full view, but is not responsive as the buttons overlap each other.

Is it best to add a @media (max-width:767px) {.col-xs-2 {width: 50%;} in the bootstrap file or change in the CSS?

Comment: you should try the 'btn-xs' and the 'btn-sm' classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On columns you can add `.col-md-6` for desktop medium devices and  `.col-xs-6` for mobile or extra small devices

Your column should look now as

`.col-md-6 col-xs-6`

Answer (score 0):

The default display for buttons in bootstrap is inline-block.

Try this on the button element:

```
display: block;
float: left; /*Optional!*/
```